# random variable on Uniform distribution max value of c

Tags: probability, statistics, optimization

To generate random variables based on the following distribution, we use a continuous uniform distribution.
 What is the value of best c?

$\ fx(x) = \frac{6}{625}(x^2+3x+5)$  0 < x < 5

$\ \frac{6}{625}(x^2+3x+5)<=c $

I coded this is R but is not correct

```
f<- function(x){0.0096*(x^2+3*x+5)}
curve(f,0,5)
f_max<-optimize(f,lower=0,upper=5,maximum = T)$objective
c<- f_max
c #0.4319903
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are doing or what your question is.  Can you perhaps explain a bit more fully.  Are you using a rejection algorithm?  What does "best" mean in the context at hand?

Comment: You use $X$ in some places and $x$ in others, but I can't tell to what extent it was intentional. In your expression for $f_x(x)$ -- note: I think you mean $f_{\color{red}{X}}(x)$ -- did you mean to have $\color{red}{x}^2 + 3 \color{red}{X}$ as you wrote? Relatedly, you refer to a uniform distribution; where is it? Is it the capital $X$? If you make all the $x$ terms in your density lower case, you have a valid density function as it is.

Comment: it is only one x (lowercase)  $$\ fx(x) = \frac{6}{625}*(x^2+3x+5)$$

Comment: In that case, echoing kimchi lover's comment: what does "best" mean? My naive interpretation of this question would be: "Find the highest value of the density function." If that's right, then your solution gives the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

A plot of the probability density function shows that the maximum occurs at $x=5$ which is $54/125=0.432$.

But if you are attempting to use efficient rejection sampling, there's no need to do so in this case.

The cumulative distribution function is

$$Pr(X\leq x)=\frac{2 x^3}{625}+\frac{9 x^2}{625}+\frac{6 x}{125}$$

for $0\leq x\leq 5$.  We can generate a random number $u$ between $0$ and $1$ and then solve for x:

$$x=\frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt[3]{1250 u+10 \sqrt{25 u (625 u+63)+53}+63}-\frac{11}{\sqrt[3]{1250 u+10 \sqrt{25 u (625 u+63)+53}+63}}-3\right)$$

The *Mathematica* code to get this result is

```
x /. Solve[(6 x)/125 + (9 x^2)/625 + (2 x^3)/625 == u, x, Reals][[1]] // ToRadicals // FullSimplify
```

Some *R* code to implement this to obtain 100 samples from this distribution might be

```
n <- 100
u <- runif(n)
x <- (-3 - 11/(63 + 1250*u + 10*sqrt(53 + 25*u*(63 + 625*u)))^(1/3) + 
  (63 + 1250*u + 10*sqrt(53 + 25*u*(63 + 625*u)))^(1/3))/2
```